# Convolución de imágenes no devuelve el resultado esperado

Tags: c++, imagen, matrices

Estoy escribiendo un código para aplicar una serie de kernels a una imagen determinada. El usuario proporciona una ruta de imagen .pgm, así como una ruta a un archivo de texto, que contiene una serie de kernels que se aplicarán a la imagen. [La imágen funciona de esta manera](https://users.wpi.edu/%7Ecfurlong/me-593n/pgmimage.html#:%7E:text=Description,8%2Dbit%20data%20per%20pixel). El archivo de texto está escrito de la siguiente manera:

```
3   //Numero de kernels
1   //Constante de escalar. Esta se multiplica por el resultado de la sumatoria.
3 3   //Dimensiones del kernel
0 -1 0   //Matriz del kernel
-1 5 -1
0 -1 0
0.11111 // Escalar del segundo kernel
3 3
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
0.003906  // Escalar del tercer kernel
5 5
1 4 6 4 1
4 16 24 16 4
6 24 36 24 6
4 16 24 16 4
1 4 6 4 1
```

Para este proyecto, estamos iterando a través de la matriz de la imagen interna (ignorando los bordes, por lo que, naturalmente, la imagen de salida será más pequeña. Y es por eso que estamos aplicando un relleno).

Ya creé y probé las funciones para cargar la imagen, los núcleos, configurar el relleno (ceros y replicación) y guardar el nuevo archivo. Todos parecen funcionar como se esperaba. Sin embargo, la función que realiza la convolución no funciona, a pesar de múltiples intentos, utilizando diferentes enfoques. El último que probé parece ser el que mejor funciona, sin embargo, todavía no funciona. Por ejemplo al pasar esta imagen:

[image: imagen original]

Con este kernel:

```
3
1
3 3
0 -1 0
-1 5 -1
0 -1 0
0.11111
3 3
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
0.003906
5 5
1 4 6 4 1
4 16 24 16 4
6 24 36 24 6
4 16 24 16 4
1 4 6 4 1
```

Debería dar este resultado:

[image: resultado esperado]

Sin embargo, esta es la salida:

[image: salida de mi programa]

Aunque el compilador no muestra errores. Este es mi código. La única función donde necesito ayuda es "aplicarKernel". Sólo algunos consejos sobre la lógica serían más que suficientes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

//TODO: Borrar memoria dinamica en todo lado

struct Kernel{
    float escalar;
    int filas;
    int columnas;
    int **matriz;

    Kernel(){}
 
    Kernel(float escalar, int filas, int columnas){
        this->escalar = escalar;
        this->filas = filas;
        this->columnas = columnas;
        this->matriz = new int*[columnas];
        for(int i = 0; i<columnas; i++){
            this->matriz[i] = new int[filas];
        }
    }
};

 int** subirImg(string rutaImg, int* filas, int* columnas);
 Kernel* subirKernel(string rutaKernel, int* numeroKernels);
 int** aplicarKernel(int** matrizImg, Kernel* kernels, int filasImagen, int 
 columnasImagen, int numKernels, int**matrizConPadding);
 int calculoMatrices(int** matrizImg, int** matrizKernel, int filasKernel, int 
 columnasKernel);
 int** agregarPadding(int opcion,int** matrizImg, int filasImagen, int columnasImagen);
 int** zeroPadding(int** matrizImg, int* filasImg, int* columnasImg);
 int** replicationPadding(int** matrizImg, int* filasImg, int* columnasImg);
 void almacenarNuevaImagen(int** matrizImg, int filasImg, int columnasImg);

 int main(){
     string rutaImg, rutaKernel,valAux;
     int filasImagen, columnasImagen,numKernels, opcionPadding;
int filasConPadding, columnasConPadding;
int** matrizImg;
int** matrizConPadding;
Kernel* kernels;

cout<<"\tBienvenido\nIngrese ruta de la imagen:\n";
getline(cin, rutaImg);
matrizImg = subirImg(rutaImg, &filasImagen, &columnasImagen);

filasConPadding = filasImagen+2;
columnasConPadding = columnasImagen+2;

cout<<"Ingrese ruta kernel:\n";
getline(cin, rutaKernel);
kernels = subirKernel(rutaKernel,&numKernels);


cout<<"Desea agregar padding de ceros(0) o de replicacion(1):\n";
getline(cin, valAux);
opcionPadding = stoi(valAux);

//TODO: Solucionar problema al agregar padding en aplicacion de kernel*/
matrizConPadding = agregarPadding(opcionPadding,matrizImg,filasImagen,columnasImagen);

     /*cout<<"Matriz:\n"<<" "<<filasImagen<<" "<<columnasImagen<<endl;
     for(int i = 0; i<filasImagen+2;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<columnasImagen+2; j++){
            cout<<matrizConPadding[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;*/
    /* cout << "Kernels: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numKernels; ++i) {
        cout << "Kernel " << i + 1 << ":" << endl;
        cout << "Escalar: " << kernels[i].escalar << endl;
        cout << "Filas: " << kernels[i].filas << ", Columnas: " << kernels[i].columnas 
 << endl; 
        cout << "Matriz:" << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < kernels[i].filas; ++j) {
           for (int k = 0; k < kernels[i].columnas; ++k) {
                cout << kernels[i].matriz[j][k] << " ";
           }
           cout << endl;
       }
       cout << endl;
    }
     cout<<endl;
 */
cout<<"Aplicando kernel...\n";
matrizImg = aplicarKernel(matrizImg,kernels,filasImagen,columnasImagen,numKernels,matrizConPadding);
cout<<"Guardando imagen convulcionada en mismo directorio...\n";
almacenarNuevaImagen(matrizImg,filasImagen,columnasImagen);
return 0;
}

int** subirImg(string rutaImg, int* filas, int* columnas){
int filasImg, columnasImg;
int** matrizImg;
string valAux;

ifstream imagen("./"+rutaImg);

if(!imagen.is_open()){
    cout<<"La imagen no ha podido abrirse\n";
    exit(1);
}
cout<<"Imagen abierta correctamente\n";

getline(imagen,valAux);
getline(imagen, valAux);
getline(imagen, valAux, ' ');
filasImg = stoi(valAux);
getline(imagen, valAux, '\n');
columnasImg = stoi(valAux);
getline(imagen, valAux);


matrizImg = new int* [columnasImg];
for(int i = 0; i<columnasImg;i++){
    matrizImg[i]= new int [filasImg];
}


stringstream flujo_imagen;
flujo_imagen<<imagen.rdbuf();
imagen.close();

string linea;
int i = 0, j=0;
while(getline(flujo_imagen,linea)){
    stringstream buffer_linea(linea);
    string valAux;
    while(buffer_linea>>valAux){
        matrizImg[i][j]= stoi(valAux);
        j++;
        if(j==columnasImg){
            j = 0;
            i++;
        }
    }

}

cout<<"PRUEBAAAAAA\n";
for(int i = 0 ; i<filasImg;i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<columnasImg; j++){
        cout<<matrizImg[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
cout<<"PRUEBAAAAAA\n";

*filas = filasImg;
*columnas = columnasImg;
return matrizImg;
}

 Kernel* subirKernel(string rutaKernel, int* numeroKernels){
     int numKernels;

    string valAux;

    Kernel* kernels;

    ifstream archivo_kernel("./"+rutaKernel);
    if(!archivo_kernel.is_open()){
         cout<<"No se ha podido abrir el archivo\n";
         exit(1);
     }
    getline(archivo_kernel, valAux);
     numKernels = stoi(valAux);

     *numeroKernels = numKernels;

     kernels = new Kernel[numKernels];


     for(int i = 0; i < numKernels; i++){
         int filasKernel,columnasKernel;
         float escalar;
         string valAux;

         getline(archivo_kernel,valAux);
         escalar = stof(valAux);
         getline(archivo_kernel, valAux, ' ');
         filasKernel = stoi(valAux);
         getline(archivo_kernel, valAux, '\n');
         columnasKernel = stoi(valAux);

        kernels[i]= Kernel(escalar,filasKernel,columnasKernel);

        for(int ii = 0;ii<filasKernel;ii++){
             getline(archivo_kernel,valAux);
             stringstream buffer_linea(valAux);
             for(int jj=0; jj<columnasKernel;jj++){
                  buffer_linea>>valAux;
                  kernels[i].matriz[ii][jj] = stoi(valAux);
             }
        }
     }

     cout<<"PRUEBAAAAAA\n";
     for(int x = 0; x<numKernels; x++){
         for(int i = 0 ; i<kernels[x].filas;i++){
             for(int j = 0; j<kernels[x].columnas; j++){
                 cout<<kernels[x].matriz[i][j]<<" ";
              }
             cout<<endl;
         }
      }
      cout<<"PRUEBAAAAAA\n";

      return kernels;
 }

  int** aplicarKernel(int** matrizImg, Kernel* kernels, int filasImagen, int 
 columnasImagen, int numKernels, int**matrizConPadding) {

     // Create a copy of the original image matrix to store the convolved image
     int** matrizCopia = new int*[filasImagen];
     for (int i = 0; i < filasImagen; i++) {
         matrizCopia[i] = new int[columnasImagen]();
     }

     // Loop through each kernel
      for (int i = 0; i < numKernels; i++) {
          int filasKernel = kernels[i].filas;
         int columnasKernel = kernels[i].columnas;
         float escalar = kernels[i].escalar;

         // Loop through each pixel of the image matrix
         for (int y = 0; y < filasImagen; y++) {
             for (int x = 0; x < columnasImagen; x++) {
                  // Apply the kernel to the image matrix at position (x, y)
                 int sum = 0;
                  for (int ky = 0; ky < filasKernel; ky++) {
                     for (int kx = 0; kx < columnasKernel; kx++) {
                         // Ensure that the kernel is applied within the bounds of the 
 image
                          int imgX = x + kx - filasKernel / 2;
                         int imgY = y + ky - columnasKernel / 2;
                          if (imgX >= 0 && imgX < columnasImagen && imgY >= 0 && imgY < 
  filasImagen) {
                             sum += matrizImg[imgY][imgX] * kernels[i].matriz[ky][kx];
                         }
                     }
                  }
                 // Apply the scaling factor and update the convolved image matrix
                matrizCopia[y][x] += sum * escalar;
             }
         }
         for(int u = 0; u<filasImagen; u++){
             for(int v = 0; v<columnasImagen; v++){
                 if(matrizImg[u][v]>255){
                     matrizImg[u][v] = 255;
                     //Doesn't seem to work every time
                 }
                 else{
                     matrizImg[u][v] = matrizCopia[u][v];
                }
             }
          }
     }

 /*    //Put the convoluted matrix inside the padded matrix. Code doesn't work with 
 this. 
     int auxFilas = 0,auxColumnas =0;
    for(int i = 1; i<filasImagen-1; i++){
         for(int j = 1;j<columnasImagen-1;j++){
             matrizConPadding[i][j]= matrizImg[auxFilas][auxColumnas];
             auxFilas++;
             auxColumnas++;
         }
    }*/

     // Output the convolved image matrix. Ideally, should output the padded matrix
     return matrizImg;
 }



 int calculoMatrices(int** matrizImg, int** matrizKernel, int filasKernel, int 
columnasKernel){
    int suma=0;
     for(int i =0; i<filasKernel; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j<columnasKernel; j++){
             suma += matrizImg[i][j] * matrizKernel[i][j];
        }
    }
     return suma;
 }

 int** agregarPadding(int opcion,int** matrizImg, int filasImagen, int columnasImagen){
     int nFilas, nColumnas;
     switch (opcion) {
         case 0:
            cout<<"Aplicando zero padding...\n";
             matrizImg= zeroPadding(matrizImg,&filasImagen,&columnasImagen);
              break;
         case 1:
            cout<<"Aplicando replication padding...\n";
            matrizImg = replicationPadding(matrizImg,&filasImagen,&columnasImagen);
            break;
        default:
             cout<<"Opcion no disponible\n";
            exit(1);
    }
     cout<<"Padding aplicado correctamente\n";
    return matrizImg;

}

 int** zeroPadding(int** matrizImg, int* filasImg, int* columnasImg){
     int nuevasFilas=(*filasImg)+2, nuevasColumnas=(*columnasImg)+2;
     int** matrizConPadding = new int*[nuevasFilas];
    for(int i = 0; i<nuevasFilas;i++) {
        matrizConPadding[i] = new int[nuevasColumnas];
     }

for(int i = 0; i<nuevasFilas;i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<nuevasColumnas;j++){
        if(i==0||i==nuevasFilas-1||j==0||j==nuevasColumnas-1){
            matrizConPadding[i][j]=0;
        }
        else{
            matrizConPadding[i][j]=matrizImg[i-1][j-1];
        }
    }
}
*filasImg = nuevasFilas;
*columnasImg = nuevasColumnas;

cout<<"PRUEBAAAAAA\n";
for(int i = 0 ; i<nuevasFilas;i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<nuevasColumnas; j++){
        cout<<matrizConPadding[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
cout<<"PRUEBAAAAAA\n";

return matrizConPadding;
 }

 int** replicationPadding(int** matrizImg, int* filasImg, int* columnasImg){
int nuevasFilas=(*filasImg)+2, nuevasColumnas=(*columnasImg)+2;
int** matrizConPadding = new int*[nuevasFilas];
for(int i = 0; i<nuevasFilas;i++) {
    matrizConPadding[i] = new int[nuevasColumnas];
}

for(int i = 0; i<nuevasFilas;i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<nuevasColumnas;j++){
        if (i == 0 || i == nuevasFilas - 1 || j == 0 || j == nuevasColumnas - 1) {
            if(i==0){
                if(j==0){
                    matrizConPadding[i][j] = matrizImg[0][0];
                }
                else if(j==nuevasColumnas-1){
                    matrizConPadding[i][j] = matrizImg[0][(*columnasImg)-1];
                }
                else{
                    matrizConPadding[i][j] = matrizImg[0][j-1];
                }
            }
            else if(i==nuevasFilas-1){
                if(j==0){
                    matrizConPadding[i][j] = matrizImg[(*filasImg)-1][0];
                }
                else if(j==nuevasColumnas-1){
                    matrizConPadding[i][j] = matrizImg[(*filasImg)-1][(*columnasImg)-1];
                }
                else{
                    matrizConPadding[i][j] = matrizImg[(*filasImg)-1][j-1];
                }
            }
            else{
                if(j==0){
                    matrizConPadding[i][j] = matrizImg[i - 1][0];
                }
                else if(j == nuevasColumnas - 1){
                    matrizConPadding[i][j] = matrizImg[i - 1][(*columnasImg) - 1];
                }
                else{
                    matrizConPadding[i][j] = matrizImg[i - 1][j - 1];
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            matrizConPadding[i][j]=matrizImg[i-1][j-1];
        }
    }
}

*filasImg = nuevasFilas;
*columnasImg = nuevasColumnas;

cout<<"PRUEBAAAAAA\n";
for(int i = 0 ; i<nuevasFilas;i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<nuevasColumnas; j++){
        cout<<matrizConPadding[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
cout<<"PRUEBAAAAAA\n";

return matrizConPadding;
}

void almacenarNuevaImagen(int** matrizImg, int filasImg, int columnasImg){
ofstream nuevo_archivo("./nuevaImagen.pgm");
nuevo_archivo<<"P5"<<endl;
nuevo_archivo<<"#WPI-ME/CHSLT generated image Ver.1.0 (0)"<<endl;
nuevo_archivo<<filasImg<<" "<<columnasImg<<endl;

int maxGris = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<filasImg; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<columnasImg; j++){
        if(matrizImg[i][j]>maxGris){
            maxGris = matrizImg[i][j];
        }
    }
}

nuevo_archivo<<maxGris<<endl;
for(int i = 0;i<filasImg;i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<columnasImg; j++){
        nuevo_archivo<<matrizImg[i][j]<<" ";
    }
}
nuevo_archivo.close();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Tu código es muy difícil de leer y por lo tanto también de modificar. Así que te voy a dar un par de ideas para que lo mejores y te resulte más fácil encontrar tu error... Básicamente parece que te estás saltando pixels y escribes donde no es.

Tu estructura de datos es un poco ineficiente, u sobre todo difícil de manejar. Este tipo de aplicaciones suelen slmacena la imagen en una structural como esta:

```c
 struct img {
   unsigned char*d;
   int stride, w, h;
}
```

El campo `d` será donde almacenes los pixels. Puedes reservarlo dinámicamente. Su tamaño será: `w *h*bpp`... Para imágenes en gris bpp=1

`stride` es el valor que te permitirá moverte por las líneas y es igual a `w*bpp + padding`. Algunos formatos como BMP requerían padding ... No el mismo padding del que tú hablas.

Con esta estructura puedes copiar datos muy Finalmente y acceder a los pixels de la siguiente forma:

```c
 *(Img.d +x*bpp +y*d.stride + componente)
```

Para una imagen en escala de grises se te queda en :

```c
*(Img.d +x + y * d.stride)
```

Implementa el filtro primero sin padding. Simplemente no processes los caracteres del borde. Cuando ese te funcione ve a por el padding. Así tendrás una implementación de referencia y si implementas tus modificaciones en pasos pequeños debería ser muy fácil corregir tus problemas.

Puedes duplicar toda la imagen para implementar la convolución, pero solo necesitas tantas líneas como el número de filas de tu filtro. Pero para no liarlo usa una imagen completa.

También observa que puedes hacer el clamping de los resultados cuando los calculas. No necesitas hacer otro paso por toda la imagen. De esa forma tampoco necesitas usar enteros para almacenar los pixels.

Espero que esto te ayude. Si consigues un código más limpio y todavía necesitas ayuda ya sabes dónde estamos.